# Solving PAT equation with 2 logs

Tags: logarithms, education

Taken from the PAT (Physics Aptitude Test):

$\log_x 25 = \log_5 x$

I've tried making them the same base but I ended up with:

$\log_5 x (\log_5 x)= 2$

or

$\log_x 25(\log_x 5) = 1$

which I then simplified to

$\log_x 5 (\log_x 5 + 1) = 1$

Not sure if the last line is correct math but I'd appreciate some help on how to solve this equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log_x 25 = 2\log_x 5=\frac{2}{\log_5 x}$ so $(\log_5 x)^2=2$, $\log_5 x=\pm \sqrt{2}$, $x=5^{\sqrt{2}}$, $x=5^{-\sqrt{2}}$

Verification: $\log_5 5^{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$; $\log_{5^{\sqrt{2}}}25=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log_5 25=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$

$\log_5 5^{-\sqrt{2}}=-\sqrt{2}$; $\log_{5^{-\sqrt{2}}}25=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log_5 25=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=-\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Didn't even see that $\log_5 x (log_5 x)$ could be changed to $(log_5 x)^2$. Thanks for the help

Comment: @NoChance: I added verification which can be done using basic log identity $\log_{b^q} a=\frac{\log_b a}{q}$

Comment: Thank you.That is good.

Answer (score 0):

A long way:

We want to find $x$ such that:
$$\log_x 25 = \log_5 x$$

I would convert both logs to the same base, and choose the common base to be $10$ in an attempt to simplify calculations. Here I write $log(x)$ to mean $log_{10}(x)$
again to simplify the looks.

$$\log_x 25 = \frac{log(25)}{log(x)}$$

$$\log_5 x = \frac{log(x)}{log(5)}$$

Since the L.H.S is equal in both of the above equations, the R.H.S is equal, we get:

$$\frac{log(25)}{log(x)}=\frac{log(x)}{log(5)}$$

Hence (we have to assume $x is not 1 because log(1)=0):

$$log(25)log(5) =log(x)log(x)$$

$$log(x)=\sqrt{log(5)log(25)}=0.98849285982$$

Now we raise both sides to power of $10$ since we use $log$ to the base $10$:

$$x=9.73851774234$$

To verify:

$$\log_{9.73851774234} 25 = \log_{5} (9.73851774234)$$

$$ 1.4142135624 = 1.4142135624$$

In fact there is another value of $x$ that satisfies the equation:

$$x=0.103$$

I obtained this value graphically.
You can see: [Desmos Plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mawpw7u7cl).